# Retrieving XML files from FTP to SharePoint online

Tags: .net, xml, sharepoint, ftp

I have an FTP account where there are XML files including news which are updated with a new xml file every couple of hours or so. I need to get data of the latest xml files to a SharePoint Online web page.

Note the following:

1. FTP has a username and password to be accessed.
2. XML file url in ftp has the following format - "ftp://ftp.somewhere.org/Directory/another/directory/XML/XMLFILENAMEHERE.xml"
3. I need to display the latest 5 news items (5 xml files) in a Sharepoint online page.

[[image: screenshot of the XML from FTP site]]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. SO is not a coding site, so please ask for specific problems that you couldn't manage to solve on your own after trying and not just post some requirements and ask for working code.